# Android StartActivtyForResult() from a Service

Tags: android, architecture, android-service

First I'm sorry for my english that is not so good :).

I am facing a problem to develop my app.

That is a general architecture scheme of my solution.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooTmE.png

To be quick, the app has to decode code bare but with two possible ways:

1. using exernal device (The constructor provides a sdk containing an android Service to   communicate with the device),
2. use the camera of the mobile using the library Zxing which is possible to manage it with intent.

The goal of my own service is to manage some business code and make transparent the choice of the tool for the user.

I believed that was a good solution but I wanted to implement it and I had different problems.

My main trouble is that I cannot execute StartActivityForResult inside the service.

Do somebody have any suggestions for my problem whether a change in the architecture or a solution for the main problem?

---

@Laurent' : You have totaly right my service acts as an API adapter.

I will try to make the expected behaviour more clear.

I have an app that needs to recognize (real) objects which have QR codes on their top. This recognition action will be done several times by the user during the life of the app.

The user chooses to launch the recognition by clicking on a button (or otherwise but he knows that the recogntion will start). So no notification is needed.

The thing is he doesn't choose the way to do the recogniton. It is why, as you said, I implement an adapter.

The adapter chooses between :

Camera mobile or external device. The first is an activity coming from the Zxing library. The second one is a service that manages the external device. This service provides an interface to get back result.

One more thing, I need that my whole implementation (adapter and co) can be re-used by other apps that will also need to do recognition.

So my thought was to implement a service as an adapter to answer my two conditions (make transparent the choice for the user - and make the recognition available for other apps).

I hope you understand my problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your architecture, your `MyOwnService` must act as an API adapter : it should provide a unified scanning API and address each external service specificities transparently.

Your expected behaviour is not clear enough to provide a solution that suits your needs but here are a few remarks that can be of some help.

Passive scanning:

- Even if there are some workarounds : **no activity should be launched from a service** (not *directly*). Never. Bad. Services are background stuff, the most they will be permitted is to *hint* users with [`Notifications`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html) (this is point 2 of Justin excellent answer).

As a consequence there's nothing as a 'popup Activities' (and that's good!). If you need to continuously scan for barcodes, even when your activity is not run, then the only way to warn users is by using status bar notification.

Active scanning:

- Inside your own activity you can `bind` to your wrapper service and make it start scanning for codebars. When it finds one it has to `message` your activity. Your Activity `message handler` has complete access to the UI to inform the user of your findings.

---

You selected **Active Scanning** in your edit, your problem is therefore to find a way for your service to actively notify your main application (the one that *started* the active scanning) that a new item has been scanned successfully.

You do NOT do this by starting a new activity (remember: this is bad) but you can `bind` to a service and/or use `Messages` between the wrapper service and the application.

I advice you take the time to read (and more time to comprehend) [this android developer article on BoundServices](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/bound-services.html) and especially the part about [`Messengers`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/bound-services.html#Messenger).

A full example of Two Way Messaging between a Service and an Activity can be found in the following android examples : [Service](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/MessengerService.html) & [Activity](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/MessengerServiceActivities.html)

Warning: designing robust, full blown AIDL-based services is a tough job.

Comment: You have totaly right my service acts as an API adapter.

I will try to make the expected behaviour more clear.

I have an app that needs to recognize (real) objects which have QR codes on their top. This recognition action will be done several times by the user during the life of the app.

The user chooses to launch the recognition by clicking on a button (or otherwise but he knows that the recogntion will start). So no notification is needed.

The thing is he doesn't choose the way to do the recogniton. It is why, as you said, I implement an adapter.

[... NEXT COMMENT]

Comment: [PREVIOUS COMMENT...]The adapter chooses between :

Camera mobile or external device. The first is an activity coming from the Zxing library. The second one is a service that manages the external device. This service provides an interface to get back result.

One more thing, I need that my whole implementation (adapter and co) can be re-used by other apps that will also need to do recognition.

So my thought was to implement a service as an adapter to answer my two conditions (make transparent the choice for the user - and make the recognition available for other apps).

I hope I am more clear

Comment: thanks, 
I will read the article about bounded service.

Just I already bind the mainActivity to the service to manage some parts of the service such as startScan or getDeviceStatus.

But I would like to let all the business part of the recognition inside the service to well separate the MainApp of the recognition part. But It seems to be difficult. 

I am going to read the article and coming back after :)

Thanks a million for your time and your interest in my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways you could solve this problem.

1) Have MyOwnService do a callback into MainActivity telling it to launch your ScanActivity.
 - This is a better approach if MyOwnService's task is only going to be running while MainActivity is running and if the user would expect the ScanActivity to come up automatically.

2) Have MyOwnService create a notification that will let the user access the ScanActivity.
 - This is a better approach if MyOwnService's task might be running longer than the life span of MainActivity. That way, you can let the user know, unobstrusively, that they might want to access the ScanActivity.

Comment: My choice would be for the first ways because the service should not send notification outside the lifecycle of my mainActivity.

But the things is, I find that a bit strange that the Main activity starts the service and then the service, if it chooses the mobile camera to scan, has to do a callback into the main activity... 
In my mind, i expected that all the business code will stay inside the service...
I am not sure if I am enought clear

Comment: I expected that all code concerning the scan and recognition will stay inside the service and the others app it needs...

Comment: I can understand your concern, but your also saying that your business code involves manipulating the UI, which shouldn't be the case. The business code should post an event back to the UI so it can decide how best to bring up the ScanActivity. At least that's how I look at it.

Comment: Hi Justin,

My business code do not modify my UI or if it does, it is by callback thanks to the interface of my own service. (Using bindService()).

The problem is to launch the activity that use camera for scanning.
As I tried to explain above. I would like to use the servie just as an ADAPTER and make this adapter available during the entiere life of the app and available for other apps. But maybe the choice of a service is not the good choice...

To be honest I am lost in the android architecture ..

Comment: What I was implying was that by having your service start an activity, it is modifying the UI by causing it to come up. If you want to insulate the MainActivity from what ScanActivity you want to start, I would suggest passing an Intent in the callback back to the main activity. That way, all the main activity has to do is call startActivity using the intent your service supplied. That should sufficiently keep things separate.

Answer (score 1):

So finally I changed my architecture.

I make the choice to delete myOwnService and to create an intermediate activity that will be my API Adaptater.

This activity will have a dialog.theme to look like a dialog box indicating that a recognition is under execution.

If the recognition uses the external device this activity will stay at the foreground otherwise the camera activity will start (Being managed by the intermediate activity).

Thank to that I can manage my result from the intermediate activity and do not have an android strange architecture, keeping my business code for the recognition outside my main app.

Service was not the good choice.

Thanks a lot for you help and your time.